# Which is better button input or form input?

Tags: forms, input, filter, checkboxes

I understand that technically they are the same thing, but from a visual UX point of view which performs better button input vs check box?

Has there been any thorough research done around this? if so please point me to it. Thanks in advance.

[image: Check box vs button input]

Comment: If you can, just test it.

Comment: Don't have time or resource at the moment. Otherwise I would.

Comment: I personally think the second option is better simply because the first one implies that I can select multiple boxes since you chose a checkbox, rather than a radio button like option 2. So option 2 wins by default for me.

Comment: Both are `<form>` inputs.

Comment: @Wanda in that case the check box wins as you can select multiple

Comment: Then I simply don't understand what this control is supposed to do here, with the label and options available..

Comment: @Wanda I would guess it's part of some filter options: "show me all cars with 4 seats", "show me all cars with 4 or 7 seats" (EDIT: Especially since I just noticed there's a [tag:filtering] tag present).

Comment: @TripeHound Ohhh, now it makes sense. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Checkbox**. Why?

- **Clear state**: Users don´t need to think which style represents the selected state.
- **Familiarity**: Used broadly in filters (eg: Amazon).
- **Accesibility**: Colorblind friendly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following as it has good scope for a user to either enter custom numbers or select from the predefined numbers.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox is better in general, because it's more visually familiar.

But in this particular case with "number of seats," checkbox wouldn't be appropriate because "number" is a sequential concept and checkbox is more for things that are categorical.